# How to pass a combobox as a parameter in Access?

Tags: ms-access

I have the following example code on a few events for a few comboboxes:

```
Private Sub cbo_oc_tours_all_Enter()
' Find the record that matches the control.
Dim rs As Object

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
    rs.FindFirst "[ID_T_OC] = " & Str(Nz(Me![cbo_oc_tours_all], Null))
    If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    
Me.cbo_oc_tours_today.Value = Str(Nz(Me![cbo_oc_tours_all], Null))

End Sub
```

I want to put this into a single function and call it from each event procedure(?). I've used the following code in the function:

```
Sub goto_record(goto_rec As ComboBox, update_rec As ComboBox)

Dim rs As Object

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
    rs.FindFirst "[ID_T_OC] = " & Str(Nz(Me![goto_rec], Null))
    If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    
update_rec.Value = Str(Nz(Me![goto_rec], ""))

End Sub
```

And I'm trying to call it using:

```
Sub cbo_oc_tours_all_Enter()

Call goto_record(cbo_oc_tours_all, cbo_oc_tours_today)
    
End Sub
```

However, I'm getting an error saying `Microsoft Access can't find the field 'goto_rec' referred to in your expression`. I'm clearly not passing the combo box in the right way but it's been a while since I've used VBA. What's my issue?

Comment: Since you pass the control directly, just access its value. Try: `rs.FindFirst "[ID_T_OC] = " & Nz([goto_rec].Value, vbNullString)`.

Comment: You should also be checking the `.NoMatch` property, not the `.EOF`.

Comment: Instead of passing combobox objects, could just pass value. @KostasK., looks like a valid answer you could write up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not pass the combo box as an object, just pass the value in the combo box. Here is an example:

```
Sub cbo_oc_tours_all_Enter()

Call goto_record(me.cbo_oc_tours_all, me.cbo_oc_tours_today)

End Sub
```

Assuming those are the names of the combo boxes themselves. Then you other function would be

```
'Using a data type of variant for example. Replace with the datatype you are using
Sub goto_record(goto_rec As Variant, update_rec As Variant)

Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
   rs.FindFirst "[ID_T_OC] = " & Str(Nz(goto_rec,0))
   If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark

'You can change this line to this if the function is in the same module as the form with the combobox
me.cbo_oc_tours_today = goto_rec

End Sub
```